# Error comparing strings?

Tags: ruby, string

When I run the following code where str is of type string:

```
def self.split(str)
    array = Array.new
    for i in 0..str.length-1
      if str[i].casecmp('a') == 0 || str[i].casecmp(':') == 0
       ...
      end
    end

    array
  end

if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME
    count = 0;
    File.readlines('C:/Users/JRQuick/Desktop/while1.test').each do |line|
      line = line.strip()
      count = count + 1

      #CHECKS IF LINE IS COMMENT
      if (line.include? '//').equal? false
        #CHECKS IF EMPTY LINE
        if (line.gsub(" ", "").length != 0)
          array = split(line)
          print array
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This error appears:

```
`block in split': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

The error us thrown on the 4th line above, which is the if statement found in split().

I have tried equals() and matches() for string comparison but they throw the same error. I have also tried eql?() which throws no error but does not correctly compare string, always returns false, even when should return true.

Along with the above I have made sure str[i] is never nil, and even tried `str[i].to_s`

Comment: What is `str`?  A regular string?

Comment: Ugh. You're trying to see whether something is -1, 0, 1 to write your own sort routine? Describing WHY you want to do what you asked might put you on the fast-track to a much better solution.

Comment: You might need to provide more context; where's the `split`?

Comment: This is a small portion of a method which mimics the split routine, it searches through the string and splits on a set of interesting characters (interests is derived from input). Overall, this is part of a recrusive-descent syntax analyzer.

Comment: @JeremyQuick Please use **@** replies when responding to a specific comment. I don't see how the error can happen here since if `str` was `nil` the block would never be entered in the first place. I'm not convinced this is where the error is yet.

Comment: @DaveNewton, I added additional code to the question, to hopefully add context.

Comment: @JeremyQuick And what's your test input look like? If I replace `...` with a simple puts and have a text file w/ random input lines, I can't reproduce the error. Oh, and you don't need to `casecmp` a colon.

Comment: @DaveNewton `x11 := (2 + 3) * 5;` is one test case that fails for me when it shouldnt.

Comment: Is this fragment part of a Class or Module definition? I don't understand the self.split part.

Comment: Oh, and `if !line.include? '//'`, but you could just match (and you should check if `//` is the *first* non-whitespace chars, otherwise trailing comments will disqualify a line, and you should check for all whitespace including `\t`. That aside, still cannot dupe, so I suspect the error is yet elsewhere.

Comment: The undefined error seems to suggest that you're trying to call str[i] when str is nil.  If str.nil?, then str[i] will throw an undefined method error.  Try updating the wrapper to be `unless (line.nil? or line.gsub(" ", "").length == 0)`.